# Why does the text leave the axes if the x coordinate is negative?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

In the following example, I would like for the text in both cases to be in the same place:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(-2,3) 
xi = -1

plt.plot(x,x)
plt.annotate('as expected',
            xy=(1, 1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(.5, .8), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-'))                 
plt.annotate('why am i here?',
            xy=(xi, 0.5), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(.5, .8), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

The location of the text in the second annotation is outside the axes, even
though I think it should be in the same place as the first annotation.
This seems to occur for any negative value of `xi`.

Comment: You realize that obviously if you want it in the same place you must specify the same `xy=` parameter right?

Comment: Indeed; thanks! I clarified that I am referring to the location of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug to me, you should report it https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues

If you want to achieve your desired result, this works (notice the negative value in `xytext` for the second annotation), but I don't think that's the way it should...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(-2,3) 
xi = -1

plt.plot(x,x)
plt.annotate('as expected',
            xy=(1, 1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(.5, .8), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-'))                 
plt.annotate('why am i here?',
            xy=(xi, 0.5), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-.5, .8), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-'))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for physical coordinate systems (points or pixels) the origin (xy) is the (bottom, left) of the  axes. If the value is negative,  the origin is from the (right, top) of the  axes.

Comment: Yes. As you can see, in both cases xy is using data coordinates, which may be negative, given the scaling. @Diziet Asahi hacked a solution by violating the rules for 'axes fraction' textcoords, but as mentioned, it is not the expected behavior.